# Planning to ask a long-term visa after tourism visa: which documents to pass the border?

Tags: germany, long-stay-visas, schengen-visas, brazilian-citizens

I am European, living and working in Germany and my girlfriend, who is Brazilian, is soon to move in with me in Germany for ten months. We plan to ask for a long-term visa for her, either for intensive German courses or for family reunion (we would marry this year in Germany). For both visas Brazilians do NOT need to ask beforehand. They can enter Germany on a short-term visa, then ask for the long-term visa at the local authorities.

But what documents are needed to enter Germany, the ones for the short or the long term visa?

If, when passing the border, she says she intends to ask for a long-term visa (which will be obvious because her return flight is ten months later) does she already need to fulfill at this moment the conditions for the long-term visa?

I'm asking this because these are quite constraining compared to the conditions of the tourist visa and it would be problematic to fulfill them right now:

- 8,640€ on a German blocked account vs "enough money for 3 months"
- in case of visa for language courses, proof of registration to ten months of intensive courses (to be paid beforehand...)

And how does she deal with entering Germany with a return flight so late?

I read that in the conditions for obtaining the Schengen 3-months visa, you need to show a return flight within three months.

Comment: why not just get married today and avoid all the troubles??

Comment: @pnuts: Sorry for the trouble. But as my question is more about the short term visa, I thought it would fit here.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Indeed. But getting married first implies being together, it cannot be done from a distance... :p So the situation would be exactly the same as she would be coming with a short-term visa, and then transition to a long term visa during the short stay. So all my questions still hold. ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should "**actually**" make and plan a short visit.  ie purchase a 2-week return ticket and actually have all plans in place to go back.  (Then, "if" you change your plans when there - so be it.)  Anyways as everyone says it's a Expats site question.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Brazilian citizens are visa-free for short visits to the Schengen area, but **only for short visits**.

In order to be allowed to enter without a visa, your girlfriend needs to **actually have plans for a short visit**, all of it, including when and how she's going to go back -- and be prepared to document those plans. The fact (?) that Germany may allow her to *change* her plans during that short visit and apply for a long-stay visit does not affect that.

After all, even though the authorities might *entertain* a long-stay application from your girlfriend during the short visit, it is not certain that they would *grant* it, and at entry the border guard needs to be convinced that if the application is denied, she would actually leave at the end of her proposed short visit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So are we necessarily supposed to buy a flight we know she is not going to take? This procedure of coming with a short-term visa and asking for a long term visa once in Germany was the answer that the immigration office gave me when I asked about what solutions exist for my girlfriend to move with me in Germany.

Comment: @Guiux: You don't know that -- unless the girlfriend is planning on staying on illegally even if her long-term application is denied. (And if _that_ is true, then she _should_ be denied entry from the beginning).

Comment: "actually have plans for a short visit ... may allow her to change her plans": I don't think that's quite true. If she goes to the consulate in Brazil and asks for a long-stay visa, they'll tell her to enter without a visa and apply for the permit afterward.

Comment: @phoog: Exactly. Here is the source from the German consulate in Brazil: http://www.brasil.diplo.de/contentblob/4107012/Daten/7245770/Merkblatt_Sprachvisum.pdf (in German). And the immigration office in my city in Germany told me the same thing.

Comment: But there is obviously a problem with the procedure... The fact that you need a return flight for a short term visa conflicts with the fact that you ask the long term visa during a short stay...

Comment: So it looks like Germany is (or claims to be) allowing Brazilians to enter without a visa in contradiction to the Schengen rules. That may so be, but in that case be sure to enter the Schengen Area directly at the _German_ external border -- the other Schengen countries probably don't respect such a derogation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes, we thought about this issue, and we planned an entry with a direct flight to Germany. ;)